# UICollectionViewController Programmatically crashing with non-nil layout parameter error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am creating a `UICollectionViewController` programmatically. No, I don't want to use IB and Storyboards like every tutorial out there. I just want to use plain code.

Here is what I have in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
// UICollectionView
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 140)];
    [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.collectionView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[PUCImageGridCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
```

I have implemented the required delegate methods and I still get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Answer (score 10):

This is what I use to initialize a [UICollectionViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

You do not need to instantiate the collectionView the controller will do it for you.  Set the frame after calling this or you can override and set the frame inside:

```
- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout{
     self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
     if (self) {
         // additional setup here if required.
     }
     return self;
}
```

I prefer to use the [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) constraints.