# How to push a UICollectionView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to push a `UICollectionViewController` when a button is pressed. I'm using this to push it:

```
RewardsCollectionViewController* rvc = [[RewardsCollectionViewController alloc] init];                 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
```

But when I tap on the button the app crashes and gives me this message:
`UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter`
In my `RewardsCollectionViewController` class I haven't done anything I just changed `numberOfItemsInSection` to `1`.

There might me a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775297/uicollectionviewcontroller-programmatically-crashing-with-non-nil-layout-paramet) but I didn't find my answer on that page. As it is somehow related to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and I have no idea what that is.

Comment: did you google the error ?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288927/uicollectionview-must-be-initialized-with-a-non-nil-layout-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `storyboard` to your `COllectionViewController` after that change your code like this

```
 RewardsCollectionViewController* rvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifer"];                 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
```

Hope this will help you